# How to get a string which contains a specific string between two full stop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In case it is too confusing, let me give you an example for better understanding.

```
DECLARE @HotelDes varchar(1000) = 'Wake up to breathtaking views of the iconic Sydney Opera House, the Harbour Bridge or Darling Harbour each morning. You will be spoiled for choice at the Shangri-La Hotel, with a day spa, fitness centre and indoor pool at your disposal. The Shangri-la Sydney is located in the historic Rocks area, where Europeans first settled in Australia in 1788. This enviable location is just 5 minutes’ walk from both the Sydney Opera House and the MCA (Museum of Contemporary Art). After a day of sightseeing, you can relax in the bathtub of your lavish marble bathroom. All rooms include free Wi-Fi and an iPod dock, as well as fluffy bathrobes and slippers. CHI, The Spa offers a luxurious escape in its private spa suites, with a range of body treatments and massages on offer. The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay. The award-winning Altitude Restaurant boasts magnificent views of the harbour. Café Mix offers international all-day dining, while the New York-inspired Blu Bar on 36 is the perfect spot for a creative cocktail.';
DECLARE @HotelCat varchar(200) = 'sauna';
```

so  what I want is string which contains word "sauna" and that string will be between two full stop.

I want the text to show "The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay" between two full stops.

I have tried:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@HotelDes,CHARINDEX('.',@HotelDes)+1, CHARINDEX('.',@HotelDes,CHARINDEX('.',@HotelDes)+1) -CHARINDEX('.',@HotelDes)-1)
```

This returns a string of " You will be spoiled for choice at the Shangri-La Hotel, with a day spa, fitness centre and indoor pool at your disposal" from first full stop.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get the string with "sauna" text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach.

```
DECLARE @HotelDes varchar(max) = 'Wake up to breathtaking views of the iconic Sydney Opera House, the Harbour Bridge or Darling Harbour each morning. You will be spoiled for choice at the Shangri-La Hotel, with a day spa, fitness centre and indoor pool at your disposal. The Shangri-la Sydney is located in the historic Rocks area, where Europeans first settled in Australia in 1788. This enviable location is just 5 minutes’ walk from both the Sydney Opera House and the MCA (Museum of Contemporary Art). After a day of sightseeing, you can relax in the bathtub of your lavish marble bathroom. All rooms include free Wi-Fi and an iPod dock, as well as fluffy bathrobes and slippers. CHI, The Spa offers a luxurious escape in its private spa suites, with a range of body treatments and massages on offer. The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay. The award-winning Altitude Restaurant boasts magnificent views of the harbour. Café Mix offers international all-day dining, while the New York-inspired Blu Bar on 36 is the perfect spot for a creative cocktail.';
DECLARE @HotelCat varchar(200) = 'sauna';


declare @s int,@e int, @cString varchar(max), @bString varchar(max), @fString varchar(max)
set @s=1
set @e= charindex('.',@HotelDes,@s)
set  @cString=SUBSTRING(@HotelDes,@s,@e)
set @bString =SUBSTRING(@HotelDes,@e+1,1000)



while @e>1

begin

if charindex(@HotelCat,@cString,1)>0 
set @fString=@cString

set @s = 1
set @e = charindex('.',@bString,@s)
set @cString = SUBSTRING(@bString,@s,@e)
set @bString = SUBSTRING(@bString,@e+1,1000)

end

select @fString
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [DATA]
FROM(
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@HotelDes, '.', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) as q
WHERE [data] LIKE '%sauna%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create table-valued split string function to achieve that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END


DECLARE @HotelDes varchar(1000) = 'Wake up to breathtaking views of the iconic Sydney Opera House, the Harbour Bridge or Darling Harbour each morning. You will be spoiled for choice at the Shangri-La Hotel, with a day spa, fitness centre and indoor pool at your disposal. The Shangri-la Sydney is located in the historic Rocks area, where Europeans first settled in Australia in 1788. This enviable location is just 5 minutes’ walk from both the Sydney Opera House and the MCA (Museum of Contemporary Art). After a day of sightseeing, you can relax in the bathtub of your lavish marble bathroom. All rooms include free Wi-Fi and an iPod dock, as well as fluffy bathrobes and slippers. CHI, The Spa offers a luxurious escape in its private spa suites, with a range of body treatments and massages on offer. The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay. The award-winning Altitude Restaurant boasts magnificent views of the harbour. Café Mix offers international all-day dining, while the New York-inspired Blu Bar on 36 is the perfect spot for a creative cocktail.';
DECLARE @HotelCat varchar(200) = 'sauna';


select splitdata+'.' from [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@HotelDes,'.')
where splitdata like '%'+@HotelCat+'%'

--Output
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay.
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

another option would be to use reverse string and charindex if you have xml unfriendly characters for cross apply solution

```
with cte
  as (select 'Wake up to breathtaking views of the iconic Sydney Opera House, the Harbour Bridge or Darling Harbour each morning. You will be spoiled for choice at the Shangri-La Hotel, with a day spa, fitness centre and indoor pool at your disposal. The Shangri-la Sydney is located in the historic Rocks area, where Europeans first settled in Australia in 1788. This enviable location is just 5 minutes’ walk from both the Sydney Opera House and the MCA (Museum of Contemporary Art). After a day of sightseeing, you can relax in the bathtub of your lavish marble bathroom. All rooms include free Wi-Fi and an iPod dock, as well as fluffy bathrobes and slippers. CHI, The Spa offers a luxurious escape in its private spa suites, with a range of body treatments and massages on offer. The hotel also offers a hot tub, sauna and sun deck so you can make the most of your stay. The award-winning Altitude Restaurant boasts magnificent views of the harbour. Café Mix offers international all-day dining, while the New York-inspired Blu Bar on 36 is the perfect spot for a creative cocktail.' as sentence
              ,'sauna' as  search_str
      )
select --charindex(search_str,sentence)
       --,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)
       --,substring(sentence,1,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)-1)
       --reverse(substring(sentence,1,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)-1))
       --,charindex('.',reverse(substring(sentence,1,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)-1)))
       reverse(
               substring(
                reverse(substring(sentence,1,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)-1))
                ,1
                ,charindex('.',reverse(substring(sentence,1,charindex('.',sentence,charindex(search_str,sentence)+1)-1)))-1
                )
               ) as col3
  from cte
```

Db Fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=66d0a45fe0dac0c6ddacff421d341ed1